# Cycle of length k with no repeated edges

Tags: complexity-theory

I need to figure out what is the minimum complexity class (L, NL, P, NPC etc..) of the following problem: Given an undirected graph G, is there exist a cycle (doesn't have to be a simple cycle) with no repeating edges, of a size at least k? (i.e. the number of edges in the cycle is at least k)

I thought that this problem can be reduced somehow to the euler cycle problem, but have no idea how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you delete the crossposted question on Math.SE [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074520/29181). This is in on-topic here. (Crossposting is not encouraged.)

Comment: Do you have any idea to obtain an upper bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-Complete.

The $\in NP$ part is simple - guess a trail and check it.

The hardness part comes from the fact Hamiltonicity on a cubic graph is hard, [as proved in Garey and Johnson book.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=578533)

(In a cubic graph, every vertex-simple path walk is edge-simple, as it can not visit a vertex more than once, except maybe the start and end vertex).

Comment: @r But it supposed to be any graph, not specifically a cubic graph. Can you explain your solution a bit more? I don't think I understand the reduction. Thanks!

Comment: @user2443613 - my reduction if you could solve your problem for any graph, you could, in particular, solve it for a cubic graph. Now if you could solve it for a cubic graph you'll be able to decide Hamiltonicity in cubic graphs, which is hard. This shows that your problem is hard, even when restricted to graphs with max degree = 3.